# Node jS express Mongoose schema validation not working fine

Tags: node.js, mongoose, node-modules

I am facing an issue in `mongoose` node js package . I have this peice of code inside a function in my express setup

```
    const SomeModelSchema = new Schema({
      test: {
          type: String,
          min:[6,'min length should be 6'],
          required: true
      },    
      sirname: {
          type: Number,
          min: [3,'min 3 length'],
          required: true,
      }      
  });

  var SomeModel = mongoose.model('SomeModel', SomeModelSchema );

  var somemodel = new SomeModel({
      test:'aj',
      sirname: '1234'    });

    var error=somemodel.validateSync()

    if(error){
      console.log(error);
    }
    console.log(error);
    return somemodel.save()
```

validation for min 6 on key `test` is not working instead it is working on `sirname` key .

Answer (score 3):

`min` validator is for Numbers, for Strings you need to use `minlength` instead.

More info: [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#built-in-validators)